# Cannot fill azure db with data. WebPage is connected to database but don't want to create tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I created website using asp.net MVC with Entity Framework Code First. It worked before on Windows Azure, the site was available publicly.

For some reason, **I deleted database** that was used to store data of my webpage. I **created new one**, similar to previous one.

I properly connected my site to database (in solution I clicked "Publish", in "Settings" there is place to type data about database, in "Destination Connection String" window I typed all needed data and clicked "Test Connection" - everything seems to be fine)

I published my site, the site works correctly, but when I go to page that gets data from database is see this error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.

In Visual Studio in "SQL Server Explorer" I can see what is in my database. In fact, **there is nothing inside** (there is one table: "__MigrationHistory" and as I suspect this is created by default).

**How can I generate all those tables again? It should generate database structure automatically.**

PS: Accidentally I deleted "migations" from my project, do you think this is the cause?

This is not my projects blame, it works OK on localhost on my computer, when I delete localDB, it generates new one without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need migrations. But you can always re-create them (well, if you removed them all it will be initial migration containing all of your previous migrations).

To quick fix you can backup and restore you database on the server. And if you need to re-create migrations do the following:

1. Backup all your data
2. Delete the entire database (local and remote), delete all migrations from code.
3. Create databases (local and remote one).
4. Run "add-migration Initial" command from PM console
5. Run "update-database" from PM console.
6. Upload your code to the server again. If database is empty, new initial migration should be automatically applied.

Comment: Thanks. You are my hero ;)

Comment: I tried this before, but what I was doing wrong, was after deleting localdb I was opening my site and then run  "add-migration Initial". Migrations was empty. Now I see, that migrations should be runned before creating db